# IMPORTXML Xpath with contains (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Current formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(
"https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/uefa-cup/20202021/3rd-qualifying-round/r59325/",
"//div[@class='match-card match-hour' and ..//td[@class='score-time ']/a[contains(@href, 'matches')]]"
)
```

I'm trying to collect this values in `//div[@class='match-card match-hour']`:
[image]

But only when `@href` in `//td[@class='score-time ']/a/@href]`  contains the word `matches`:

[image]

Example Link in `Apollon 0 - 5 Lech Pozan`:

https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2020/09/23/europe/uefa-cup/apollon-limassol/kks-lech-poznan/3360423/
**Note that the link contains the word `matches`**

> Why only when there is this text?
>
> Because on some pages of this website the place where the results of
> the matches are located does not contain links to the match, only
> those with the word 'matches'.

Comment: The values are all `FT`; is that your expected output?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the output value you expect from your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @JackFleeting hello, on this specific page everyone is ```FT```, but on other pages on the same site, no. In some of them there is no exist ```@href``` in ```'score-time'```, so I need to filter only when there is a link(```@href```) linked to ```'score-time'``` and this links contains ```'matches'``` in your text.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated the question to try to clarify what I need.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and added information, I proposed a modified formula as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In that case, 35 `FT` values are retrieved. If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML you want to retrieve has the structure as follows.

```
<td class="day ">
  <div class="match-card match-hour">FT</div>
</td>
<td class="team team-a ">
  <a href="/teams/cyprus/apollon-limassol/518/" class="flag_16 right_16 cyprus_16_right" title="Apollon">Apollon</a>
</td>
<td class="score-time ">
  <a href="/matches/2020/09/23/europe/uefa-cup/apollon-limassol/kks-lech-poznan/3360423/">
    <span class="extra_time_score">0 - 5</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

In this case, I thought that the xpath might be `//div[@class='match-card match-hour' and ../../td[@class='score-time ']/a[contains(@href, 'matches')]]`. So how about the following modified formula?

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(
"https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/uefa-cup/20202021/3rd-qualifying-round/r59325/",
"//div[@class='match-card match-hour' and ../../td[@class='score-time ']/a[contains(@href, 'matches')]]"
)
```

- In this HTML, `//div[../../td[@class='score-time ']/a[contains(@href, 'matches')]]` and `//div[../../td[@class='score-time ']]` might be able to be also used as the xpath.

#### Result:

[image]